# migrate perforce depot from windows to linux

Tags: perforce

I am trying to migrate Perforce depot from Windows to Linux and having issues accessing files in linux after the migration. Following are the steps I followed to migrate:
On Windows I ran following commands:

```
p4d -r P4ROOT -xv
p4d -r P4ROOT -jc finalcheckpoint
```

Then copied the depot onto Ubuntu and ran following commands:

```
p4d -r P4ROOT -jr finalcheckpoint
p4d -r . -p localhost:1666
p4 verify -q //...
```

I didn't get any errors while running p4 verify, but when I try to checkout files I am getting error - Path not found.

Am I missing any step here? If any one has migrated from Windows to Linux could you please share the steps taken to migrate.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

There is a big difference moving from Windows to Linux - you are typically moving from a case-insensitive platform to a case-sensitive platform. There is a very good and detailed knowledge base article that details this on the main perforce.com web site: http://kb.perforce.com/article/75/cross-platform-perforce-server-migration

Your steps look like they are more or less correct, though you never updated the internal line-endings for the files. The KB article recommends this short shell + perl script:

```
find . -type f -name '*,v' -print -exec perl -p -i -e 's/\r\n/\n/' {} \;
```

Your path not found error is likely a mismatch in your client workspace definition. I would suggest creating a new one to test with and ensure the paths you are using are correctly specified paying special attention to any upper or lowercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use p4migrate tool
ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/tools/p4-migrate/p4migrate.html

check the part

**Migrating from Windows to Unix**